# Polymer iron-ajax binding value to paper-item in repeat template

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, polymer

I am trying to get data from an URL and bind to a paper-dropdown-menu.
The following code is working:

```html
<template is="dom-bind">
    <paper-dropdown-menu id='ddl-node' label="Select Node">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="data-val">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="item">
                <paper-item value="100">{{index}} - {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <iron-ajax id="ajax-node" url="site/get-data" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}" ></iron-ajax>
</template>
```

It could bind all data to content of paper-item as below:

```html
<paper-item value="100">0 - 100 - Item 1</paper-item>
<paper-item value="100">1 - 103 - Item 2</paper-item>
```

---

I bind `{item.id}` to attribute `id` of `paper-item` as following.
It is also working:

```html
<paper-item id="{{item.id}}">{{index}} - {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</paper-item>
```

The results:

```html
<paper-item id="100">0 - 100 - Item 1</paper-item>
<paper-item id="103">1 - 103 - Item 2</paper-item>
```

---

I want to bind `{item.id}` to attribute `value` of `paper-item` as following.
But it's NOT work:

```html
<paper-item value="{{item.id}}">{{index}} - {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</paper-item>
```

The results:

```html
<paper-item>0 - 100 - Item 1</paper-item>
<paper-item>1 - 103 - Item 2</paper-item>
```

Questions: How to make this case works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use the [attribute binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding)?

```
<paper-item value$="{{item.id}}">{{index}} - {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</paper-item>
```

Comment: Notice the **dollar sign**

Comment: Works like a charm!